# read in parquet files from data lake and have the 'Modified' time as parameter? pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I want to read in parquet files from the data lake gen 2. currently

```
base_path = /mnt/mountpoint/sales/
```

Under sales I have a date structured directory format.

```
-sales
----yyyy
------mm
--------dd
------------hh_mm_ss
```

but under day I have more subdirectories using timestamp. I want to read from the most recent timestamp directory (only the parquet file specifically, there are log files beginning with '_' under here too)

Ideally -would love if the approach could take into account if the 'dd' folder doesnt exist and traverse to the last 'dd' thats available and pick up from there. I have this function so far that    picks up all the timestamp directories.

```
def find_parquets(dbfs_ls_list):
    parquet_list = []
    if isinstance(dbfs_ls_list, str):
        # allows for user to start recursion with just a path
        dbfs_ls_list = dbutils.fs.ls(todays_metadata_path)
        parquet_list += find_parquets(dbfs_ls_list)
    else:
        for file_data in dbfs_ls_list:
            if file_data.size == 0 and file_data.name[-1] == '/':
                # found subdir
                new_dbdf_ls_list = dbutils.fs.ls(file_data.path)
                parquet_list += find_parquets(new_dbdf_ls_list)
            elif '.parquet' in file_data.name:
                parquet_list.append(file_data.path)
    return parquet_list
```

Comment: Are you looking to stream (keep watching the folder and process files as they arrive, say every X minutes) or do batch processing (wake up every X mins and process the latest file)?

Answer (score 0):

Your partitioned DataFrame (pdf_1) might looks like this, if I am not wrong.

```
+---+-----------+----+-----+---+--------+
| id|       name|year|month|day|    time|
+---+-----------+----+-----+---+--------+
|  1|Bartholomeo|2022|   10| 18|11:54:07|
| 27| Philippine|2020|   10| 13|22:25:52|
| 40| Ermengarde|2021|    8| 28|16:43:29|
| 29|  Frederich|2020|    6| 27|16:46:43|
| 46|  Giselbert|2021|    5| 16|12:55:52|
+---+-----------+----+-----+---+--------+
```

1. First read the parquet file at top level (../year) and get the latest record detail

```
pdf_1 = spark.read.parquet("path/to/partitioned/parquet/")

pdf_2 = pdf.orderBy("year","month","day","time")

latest_record = pdf_2.tail(1)[0]

year = latest_record["year"]

month = latest_record["month"]

day = latest_record["day"]

time = "%3A".join(latest_record["time"].split(":")) # The time folder name stored in S3 looks like "time=08%3A49%3A05"
```

2. Use this details in your spark read method as file Path to read only the latest records you have

```
pdf_3 = spark.read.parquet(f"path/to/partitioned/parquet/year={year}/month={month}/day={day}/time={time}/")

pdf_3.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-------+
| id|   name|
+---+-------+
| 13|Griffie|
+---+-------+
```